# Matlab runtime monotonically increases by independent runs

Tags: matlab, optimization, runtime, gurobi, cpu-time

I am trying to solve a mixed integer linear program via YALMIP using Gurobi optimizer. I solve a problem which has a specific result I know. However, when I start Matlab in my computer for the first time it is being solved in 0.5 seconds. I clear everything and run the code again. The same result is coming in 0.8 seconds. Then, 1 seconds and so on. How can I really fix this? I am clearing the workspace after each run!

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. Is there anything else running in the background that can affect this?

Comment: @SardarUsama Thank you for your answer. I found the reason. Even though Workspace is cleaned, YALMIP needs the following codes:
list = whos;for i = 1:length(list);if strcmp(list(i).class,'sdpvar');clear(list(i).name);end;end
yalmip('clear')

Comment: What's the reason?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/yalmip/cJCoBXUUF_4
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/yalmip/VNoBeBKc9vM

Comment: I am using clear. you can be right, maybe clear all can help. However, now I added the yalmip clear command at  the end of each iteration. Now it is very fast (and I dont need to clear other necessary variables)

Comment: Glad to know. Btw you may be interested in knowing what `clear` does with various combinations: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clear.html#input_argument_d119e123958

Comment: thanks :) I will check that